# verification: find a function $f$ such that $\frac{df}{d\phi} = \sin(\theta+\beta)\, \delta(\phi-\theta-\beta)$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

**Comments**

I initially posed the problem statement incorrectly. The problem statement has been altered.

**Problem Statement**:

By $\delta$ I denote the Dirac delta function. By $\frac{df}{d\phi} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ I denote a function defined by $$\frac{df}{d\phi} = \sin(\theta+\beta)\, \delta(\phi-\theta-\beta),$$
which is valid for $\phi \in [0, \pi]$, $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ and $\beta \in  [0, 2\,\pi)$. Find a function $f$ that satisfies the equation above?

**Solution**:

> Let $f$ be a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(\phi) = H(\phi-\theta-\beta)\,\sin(\theta+\beta) + K,$$ which is valid for $\phi \in [0,\pi]$, $\phi \in [0,\pi]$, and $\beta \in [0,2\pi]$.  I assert that $f$ satisfies the equation $\frac{df}{d\phi} = \sin(\theta+\beta)\, \delta(\phi-\theta-\beta)$.

**Demonstration**

To prove this, I'm simply going to the derivative of my solution.

\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{d\phi}[f(\phi)] 
&= 
\dfrac{d}{d\phi}[H(\phi-\theta-\beta)\,\sin(\theta+\beta) + K]
\\
&= 
\dfrac{d}{d\phi}[H(\phi-\theta-\beta)\,\sin(\theta+\beta)]
\\
&= 
\sin(\theta+\beta)\,\dfrac{d}{d\phi}[H(\phi-\theta-\beta)]
\\
&= 
\sin(\theta+\beta)\,\delta(\phi-\theta-\beta)\dfrac{d}{d\phi}[\phi-\theta-\beta]
\\
&= 
\sin(\theta+\beta)\,\delta(\phi-\theta-\beta) 
\end{align}

Comment: Note that [1] doesn't say the dirac delta can be integrated by a RS integral, but rather its integral can be defined as a RS integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my answer is correct. Post closed

Answer (score 2):

The distribution $\delta(\phi+\beta)\sin(\phi+\beta)$ is defined by multiplication of smooth functions and deltas which would just be $\sin(-\beta+\beta)\delta(\phi+\beta) = 0$ so your solution isn't correct.

Another way to see this is to take the derivative of your solution: $$(H(\phi+\beta)\cos(\phi+\beta))'= \delta(\phi+\beta)\cos(\phi+\beta) - H(\phi+\beta)\sin(\phi+\beta)$$ $$ = \delta(\phi+\beta) - H(\phi+\beta)\sin(\phi+\beta)$$
which is definitely not equal to the original distribution we started off with.